# Capistrano -- Could not find *** in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

When deploying a rails app via Capistrano, I keep getting the error:

```
Could not find *** in any of the sources
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add this to top of my deploy.rb

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar problem. reinstall rake and create soft link in /usr/bin doesn't work for me. I add the environment variable in my deploy.rb

```
set :default_environment, {
  :PATH => '$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:$PATH',
  :GEM_HOME => '$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353',
  :GEM_PATH => '$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the same error with another app, and the solution for me was to add `sudo` before `bundle install`. The simple version works just as well--without error messages--it just strangely left some of the gems out.